# Как открыть PopUp-окно в ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Добрый день!

Подготовил код, чтобы открыть окно. Однако, при клике на кнопку вызова PopUp не появляется.

Вот JS-код :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnGetRowValues(r) {
  
        pcMeasurementsChoice.SetContentUrl('PageProgress.aspx?Page=FormMSQQ_MI.aspx?pos=' + ';msys_id=' + r[0].toString());
        pcMeasurementsChoice.Show();
    }   

    function CustomButtonClickMSQQ(s, e) {
        if (e.buttonID == 'btnEditMSQQ')
            s.GetRowValues(e.visibleIndex, "msys_id", function (r) { OnGetRowValues(r); });
        else if (e.buttonID == 'btnInsertMI')
                 s.GetRowValues(e.visibleIndex, "msys_id;msys_block_id", function (r) { OnGetRowValues(r); });
    };
</script>
```

И фрагмент кода разметки:

```
 <dx:GridViewCommandColumn Name="CommandButtons" ButtonType="Image" VisibleIndex="0"
                ShowClearFilterButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowNewButton="true">
                <CustomButtons>
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="btnInsertMI" Text="Выбрать СИ к Блоку"
                        Image-AlternateText="Добавить СИ к заявке" Image-SpriteProperties-CssClass="spr_folder_add12" />

                </CustomButtons>
```

Когда кликаю на кнопку, PopUp не появляется. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, а где Вы вызываете эти функции? Нигде в разметке упоминания клиентской обработки клика нет.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения. <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="CustomButtonClickMSQQ" CallbackError="function(s, e) { OnCallbackErr('msgUser', e); }" />

Comment: Отображаются ли какие-нибудь ошибки в консоли браузера? Есть ли сетевые ошибки?

Comment: Только warning: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".

Answer (score 0):

Принудительно написал всё напрямую в файле JS. Заработало. 
Видимо, дело в ascx-форме, которая не воспринимала команды из

Вопрос решён.